# Low voltage micro-controllers

Tags: microcontroller, voltage

Most of the ultra low power micro-controllers need around 1 V to work. Are there micro-controllers which need much lower voltage, say < 0.5 V? Is it even theoretically possible?

Comment: couldn't you just put a DC-DC converter at the input of whatever microcontroller to allow (almost) any input voltage that you have access to?

Comment: @costrom: The key idea with a lot of low voltage logic devices is that the lower the voltage, the lower the overall power consumption. Additionally with smaller on die features, you need to go lower with voltage also, same for higher frequencies (slew rate).

Comment: Its possible e.g.: https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/6177101/ https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/4895693/

Answer (score 1):

They are projecting voltages in the < 0.5~0.6V for the 4-5nm node. The cost will be very, very high and few companies will be able to afford it, so it is unlikely to be applied to general purpose microcontrollers, more likely for powerful SOCs used in mobile phones and tablets. General purpose microcontrollers tend to be generations behind the state-of-the-art, and in some cases employ cast-off production equipment that can no longer produce state-of-the-art memory or processor chips.

Samsung and TSMC, and probably others, have roadmaps. The transistors  will be nanowire (gate all around) or finFET (the latter current used in processors), not conventional transistors.

Answer (score 0):

there's 65,000 microcontrollers on digikey, the lowest one is .9V

[Product Index > Integrated Circuits (ICs) > Embedded - Microcontrollers](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/integrated-circuits-ics/embedded-microcontrollers/685?k=microcontroller)

They all use silicon.

In the future, other transistors than silicon can theoretically go 0.1 volt

[Flat tunneling transistor operates at 0.1V](http://www.eenewseurope.com/news/flat-tunneling-transistor-operates-01v)

but low voltage is like moving a train through a wire, it heats up, whereas high voltage is like moving a bullet, it's small amperage but massive voltage.

Comment: Many of these actually require a higher voltage for operation; the value extracted into the selector is either for a backup clock, memory, wakeup logic etc, or the input to an on-board DC/DC.  It will take a bit more detailed search to find any CPU cores that actually operate at 0.9v, if there are indeed any in that selection.

Answer (score 0):

It is theoretically possible to have a core supply voltage where static CMOS logic operates down towards a few times nkT/q. [Schrom et al., “On the lower bounds of CMOS supply voltage,” Solid-State Electronics, vol. 39, no. 4, 1996]

A few practicalities of the manufacturing (like transistor threshold fluctuations) typically limit the supply voltage to somewhere near 100mV-200mV. However the maximum operating frequency will be very low, so static leakage will dominate the energy spent per computation. At some point, usually between 300mV-400mV (dependent on technology and circuit), it becomes more efficient to 
cycle between an active state (doing computation at the voltage which conserves the most energy) and a deep sleep state (reducing leakage).

Commercially there are at least some MCUs from Ambiq Micro which can operate with a core voltage [down to 0.3V](https://ambiqmicro.com/spot-technology/)

Most electrical interfaces, analog circuits, and Flash memory require larger voltages anyway, so it might not make sense to have such a low input supply voltage to an MCU.